# Reading from Input File issues .java

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    public class ZacharyMoskovRunTeam2
    {
      public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
      {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        File myFile = new File("players2.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
        String teamName;
        String playername;
        String position;
        String byeWeek;
        int numberOfPlayers=0;
        int numberOfRB=0;
        int numberOfWR=0;
        int salary=0;
        int totalsalary=0;
        boolean quarterback= false;
        boolean tightend=false;
        boolean newData=true;
        boolean newData2=false;

        //newData2 = keyboard.nextBoolean();

        teamName = inputFile.nextLine();

        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {

          playername = inputFile.nextLine();
          position = inputFile.nextLine();
          salary = inputFile.nextInt();
          byeWeek = inputFile.nextLine();
          totalsalary = totalsalary + salary;
          if (position.equals("qb"))
            quarterback=true;
          if (position.equals("te"))
            tightend= true;
          if (position.equals("rb"))
          numberOfRB++;
          if (position.equals("wr"))
            numberOfWR++;
          numberOfPlayers++;
        }

        System.out.println(teamName);
        System.out.println("     Salary: $"+ totalsalary);
        System.out.println("     "+numberOfPlayers+ " players");
        if(quarterback)
          System.out.println("     Quarterback");
        else
          System.out.println("     no Quarterback");
        if(tightend)
          System.out.println("     Tight End");
        else
          System.out.println("     no Tight End");
        System.out.println("     "+numberOfRB+" Running Backs");
        System.out.println("     "+numberOfWR+" Wide Recievers");
        if(quarterback && tightend && numberOfRB >=2 && numberOfWR >= 2 && numberOfPlayers >=6 && numberOfPlayers <=10 && totalsalary <= 30000000)
          System.out.println(teamName + " meets the team requirements");
        else
          System.out.println(teamName + " does not meet the team requirements");
        inputFile.close(); 
      }
    }
```

So Im trying to get this to read a file players1.txt/players2.txt that has the info and Im getting the following errors:

```
> java.util.InputMismatchException
>    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
>    at ZacharyMoskovRunTeam2.main(ZacharyMoskovRunTeam2.java:33)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Here is an exmaple of the txt https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/blackboard.learn.xythos.prod/57b4adf217ab9/5059169?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27players1.txt&response-content-type=text%2Fplain&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20191207T170624Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=21599&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIL7WQYDOOHAZJGWQ%2F20191207%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=bc974b6fd3f5c4f3192d619957af9ef36cb80c71e78e4ec9039afd649656247f

Comment: This does not look like javascript.

Comment: Link inaccessible. Your file must be posted *here.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Exception is caused because of the use of `scanner.nextInt()` at line 33. The exception provides you with a ton of information especially regarding the line of error. Exceptions are your friend.

The reason for the `InputMismatchException` is because the Scanner tokenizes the input file with whitespaces by default. So the next token which was being scanned is not the `nextLine` but the `CRLF-newline` character. This is my claim. Need to run more debug print statements to confirm this.

To fix this problem, you can wrap that line with this method  `Integer.parseInt()` [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)). This fixes your problem.

So the fix was in line 33: `salary = Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine());`. This will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @JourneyMan I'll be honest I'm a college student learning this is this was the unit throwing me off thanks for the help!

Comment: @ZacharyMoskov I realized as much. Please accept my answer as the solution to your problem. This helps me!

Comment: Line terminators *are* whitespace.

Comment: @user207421 Thank you correcting me. Scanner javadoc ```A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace```.